# Communities that celebrate menarche

Tags: minhag, women, niddah, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, parties-celebrations

Are there traditional communities that have rituals celebrating (or otherwise marking the occurrence of) a girl's first menses?  If so, what do those rituals look like?

(For purposes here, let's define a "traditional ritual" as something invented before 1920.)

Comment: Is this question inspired by anything?

Comment: @Daniel nothing specific.  Why?

Comment: Just seems like a kind of random question to me. (Interesting, though, so you get my +1 [or you will tomorrow... I've reached my vote limit for today].)